# How can I check if ports 465 and 587 are open with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, smtp, ports

I'm trying to use PHPMailer to send e-mails with SMTP and gmail. The exact script am using works on other servers but it is not working on this particular hosting company's server.

I have checked the `phpinfo()` and it tells me that `allow_url_fopen` is  `on` and there are no `disabled_functions` like `fopen` listed.

The script fails and it tells me either:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
```

or else

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

I'm assuming this is because it can not connect, because again this work on other servers and the authentication credentials are correct.

So I ask more generally, is there a way I can use PHP or jailshell `ssh` to check and see if the ports are actually open or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can check for open/available ports with `fsockopen`:

```
$fp = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 25, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if (!$fp) {
    // port is closed or blocked
} else {
    // port is open and available
    fclose($fp);
}
```

...where `5` is the timeout in seconds until the call fails.

This is probably due to a firewall issue where your hosting provider is blocking you from connecting to outbound sockets and/or specific ports. Keep in mind that it is a very usual security configuration to block outbound SMTP ports. Back in the day, only port `25` was blocked, but I'm starting to see more and more SSL variants being blocked as well.

Most providers and hosting companies will only allow you to connect to their own SMTP server to prevent spammers from relaying junk mail.

Comment: +1 For the record, this is the same method PHPMailer uses to connect to the SMTP server (except with longer timeout and retries).

Comment: Thanks. I also learned that even though the port is open sometimes relaying is disabled. Any way to check that with PHP?

Comment: @cwd: You need to send the appropriate SMTP commands and check the responses using `fwrite` and `fread` on the handle returned by `fsockopen`.

Comment: @netcoder - any tips on what those would be? The thing is that I was using the PHPMailer library, but I think the firewall on the remote server was not set up to allow relaying, so I believe PHPMailer was actually trying to handshake with the local SMTP client, although it didn't realize this, and so was returning a `Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data` error (for the wrong server). It would just be nice if there was a way to check that, or if PHPMailer checked that. ps: you nailed the firewall aspect. thanks for a great answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had set up smtp.googlemail.com as SMTP server in my forum. It worked well for a long time until it stopped recently. After a long and frustrating investigation I found your answer and it explains perfectly what is happening: my provider redirects outgoing SMTP connections to localhost where authentication fails.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me. I keep getting `$fp = false`, even though nothing is listening on `localhost`, port `81`. What could be the issue?