# Check if anything is listening in a port in PHP

Tags: php, port

I want to use PHP to check if anything is listening to `localhost:81`, to ensure that is available for a PHP built in server to run on.

i.e. I want to check if the following would run properly `php -S localhost:81`.

Now if something is already listening on port 81 (e.g. Apache), this will of course cause problems.

I read the following: [How can I check if ports 465 and 587 are open with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127691/how-can-i-check-if-ports-465-and-587-are-open-with-php) and the solution did not seem to work.

i.e.:

```
$fp = fsockopen('localhost', '81', $errno, $errstr, 5);
var_dump($fp); // returns false
if (!$fp) {
    // port is closed or blocked
    echo "CLOSED!";
    return false;
} else {
    // port is open and available
    echo "OPEN!";
    fclose($fp);
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately the above keeps returning "CLOSED!" even though its not.

I also get the following error message:

```
PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to localhost:81 (Connection refused)
```

How do I solve my problem?

Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Why you’re using `@`...

Comment: let's dump the error string, what is in it? Also add the  `fclose($fp);` in the closed case.

Comment: @Samr Updated answer. I just didn't want to show warnings when port is closed or blocked.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure the port is opened?

Comment: @karacsi_maci There's no need to add `fclose()` in the `if()` block, since the socket was never actually opened!

Comment: I mean nothing is using that port. i.e. I want to check if `php -S localhost:81` would work correctly. And it works fine cause nothing is listening to port 81.

Comment: @BenM Thank you, I did not know that.

Comment: No, the fact that something doesn't use the port doesn't mean it's available. You might have some firewall rules that disallow it.

Comment: ah I see. So is there a way to check if a port is available for PHP server to run on

Comment: @JanHolas I agree with you about the Firewall aspect.

Comment: @YahyaUddin Do you wish to test the port number being used by the PHP server? Or retrieve a list of available, open ports?

Comment: @BenM I want to check if anything is listening on that port. i.e. can I run `php -S localhost:81` correctly?

Comment: I think you have it other way around. When the code above says "closed", that means you can run the PHP Server, because no other application is using it. It will then start listening on port 81, so the code above would return "open" - eg. something is listening (the PHP Server in this case) and you can communicate, unless it's blocked by firewall of course.

Comment: @JanHolas I'm a bit confused. Dosen't `fsockopen` open a new socket. Therefore if something is already on the socket, I shouldn't be able to create a new socket. Am I right in saying that?

Comment: No, not really, it opensa new connection with a socket, which needs to be created beforehand (for example by running the server). So if there is nothing listening on the given socket  (server and port) and you get the CLOSED message, you are probably free to create one. You can try it by running the server `php -S localhost:81` and then running the above script again. It should give you OPEN message - you are connected and then you can send commands.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should actually check to see if `fsockopen()` has returned a `resource`:

```
$connection = @fsockopen('localhost', '81');

if (is_resource($connection))
{
    echo 'Open!';
    fclose($connection);
    return true;
}
else
{
    echo 'Closed / not responding. :(';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Its the same issue! `$fp` is being set to false

Comment: @YahyaUddin Then the port is either closed or not responding. The port may also not be correctly forwarded or available to accept inbound and outbound connections.